# Bluetooth Gatt Server Android Device Null

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello everyone i wanted to ask this question since i have a problem with Android Client/Server over BLE.

The problem: Client connect's to Server and server accept's connection from the client. Client is visible at that stage. After when the Server receives onCharacteristicRead request from the Client the device name is no longer available and fully gone only the address i believe is there but the address is not the same anymore for that device but a connection exists.

Additional information: I have found out that there is a problem with the Client / Server Gatt callbacks for onConnectionUpdate and ServerUpdateConnection they are available publicly but not available to be override. Any ideas here also i think it's a bug in the system itself.

Here is the callback from the Server side it's a standard callback nothing special. Both devices are advertising with their name and are detected on the first connected state after that null for server side.

```
mGattServer = bluetoothManager.openGattServer(mAppContext.get(), new BluetoothGattServerCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothDevice device, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(device, status, newState);

        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            if (device.getName() != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Connected SERVER for device: " + device.getName());
            } 
        }
        else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTING) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SERVER Attempting to connect...");
        }
        else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Disconnected SERVER WITHOUT CONNECTION.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceAdded(int status, BluetoothGattService service) {
        super.onServiceAdded(status, service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicReadRequest(device, requestId, offset, characteristic);

        Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothGattServerCallback.onCharacteristicReadRequest with " + device.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
        super.onCharacteristicWriteRequest(device, requestId, characteristic, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
        Log.d(TAG, "BluetoothGattServerCallback.onCharacteristicWriteRequest with " + value.length + " bytes" + " : " + characteristic.getUuid());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorReadRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, int offset, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor) {
        super.onDescriptorReadRequest(device, requestId, offset, descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDescriptorWriteRequest(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, boolean preparedWrite, boolean responseNeeded, int offset, byte[] value) {
        super.onDescriptorWriteRequest(device, requestId, descriptor, preparedWrite, responseNeeded, offset, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecuteWrite(BluetoothDevice device, int requestId, boolean execute) {
        super.onExecuteWrite(device, requestId, execute);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationSent(BluetoothDevice device, int status) {
                    super.onNotificationSent(device, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMtuChanged(BluetoothDevice device, int mtu) {
        super.onMtuChanged(device, mtu);
        Log.d(TAG,"SERVICE GATT SERVER MTU SIZE " + mtu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPhyUpdate(BluetoothDevice device, int txPhy, int rxPhy, int status) {
        super.onPhyUpdate(device, txPhy, rxPhy, status);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPhyRead(BluetoothDevice device, int txPhy, int rxPhy, int status) {
        super.onPhyRead(device, txPhy, rxPhy, status);
    }

});
```

UPDATE:

Client - Connecting - Server after that Server has device name null

Server/Client - Connecting Client/Server has device name and null

Both Client/Server have 2 connections with name and null

If you only do Client / Server each device play each role you will see
the problem. Server will get null device name.

If you have both it will get the name but will double the connection for read/write on each side and each will have the device name but the connection for the send/receive will be the nullable one.

Devices i used: S21+ and Nexus 5X

Any solution to that problem?

I can provide bug-reports if needed.

Thank you! Appreciate any feedback and help.

Comment: What do you mean by the device is no longer available? How are you determining availability? Is it by the charactistic writes failing, or by not seeing the device while scanning?

Comment: Sorry let me update the question. Device name is gone not the actual bluetoothDevice object.

Comment: it might be part of the device protocol that it looses the name once connection has been established. not really sure though. please refer to any documentation you have

Comment: Truly i am fully lost i get this whenever it is connected to the gatt server. It seem's to work fine. And i lose the name on all the other callbacks...i am trying to setAlias it happens the same thing..

Comment: If you guys can just try to provide a simple implementation that connect's client/server 1 device is server the other client and you will see it. I don't really get why the advertisement is in size also there is no problem with that...

Comment: The other thing to see here is the timeout problem. Is there a way to set the disconnect timeout for the device? Thanks

Comment: I have updated also the question so it is a bit more clearer.

Comment: @nikiizvorski did you find any solution? I have faced with same problem if client has android 13

Comment: There is no fix for this. That's the internal design. It won't be changed. Some of it was a problem of Samsung Developer team for which they shipped an update. Not sure about other manufacturers.